# Pgfplot/tikz plot creation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=middle,
                xmin=-10, xmax=15,
                ymin=-200, ymax=260,
                xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={below right},
                ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={above left},
                xtick={-10,1,15},
                ytick={-200, 25, 250},
                tick style={thick},
            ]
            \addplot[blue,thick,samples=100] {x^3-9*x^2-30*x+200};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When i enter this code i get this:[image]

But what im really going for is something like this: [image]

Which means that i have a few problems, that i can't figure out how to solve.

1. The function that i'm trying to plot(x^3 - 9x^2 - 30x + 200) doesn't fully render. I'm not sure, what to do about this.
2. I would like to make "ghost ticks" on the axes, that are visible, but doesn't have a number attached to them. Also, i would like to display the numbers 250 and 15 without the "ticks" being on top of the arrows.
3. If i were to make the numbers on the axis smaller, how would i do that?

I'm sorry if the answers to this is obivous, i have only recently started using LaTeX.

**New Question:**
This is such a small thing. I don't want to create an entirely new post just for this.

This is my current code

```
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[width=14cm,
            axis lines=middle,
            grid=major,
            xmin=-5, xmax=50.5,
            ymin=-2, ymax=10.5,
            xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={right},
            ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={above},
            tick style={thick},
            ticklabel style={font=\normalsize},
            xtick={0,5,...,50}, extra x ticks={-5}, extra x tick style={grid=none},
            ytick={0,2,...,10}, minor ytick={-1,1,...,9},extra y ticks={-2}, extra y tick style={grid=none},
            legend entries={0.5x},
                    legend style={
                at={(0.8,0.937)},
                anchor=north,
                legend columns=1},
                legend cell align={left}
        ]
        \addplot[blue,thick,samples=100,domain=-5:50] {sqrt(x)};
        \addplot[red,thick,samples=100,domain=-5:50] {0.5*x};
        \legend{$f(x)=\sqrt{x} \; {,} \; x \geq 0$ , $g(x)=0.5x$}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

It shows this:
[image]

My question: Why doesn't the graph `sqrt(x)` fully show/ go all the way to (0,0)?

Comment: Just add `domain=-10:15` to your `\addplot` options it specifies the plot x-range. Some side notes : it is not necessary to use `tikz` before `pgfplots` as the latter already does the job for you. And if you want an `axis` of width `\textwidth`, just add `width=\textwidth` to the `axis` options. See `pgfplots` manual for all options !

Comment: You're saying that i dont need to add the `\usepackage{tikz}`?

Comment: This site is not made for evolving questions. The reason why your plot does not "fully render" is that the points where you take the square root of a negative number are discarded. To plot the square root all the way down to zero, make sure that 0 is among the samples. This can be achieved e.g. with `\addplot[blue,thick,samples=111,domain=-5:50,smooth] {sqrt(x)};`. Note that I am not supposed to add this information *here*. Rather, you are supposed to ask separate questions for follow-up questions.

Comment: Alright, i had no idea that was how it worked. I'm sorry! I assume that i can still ask questions about your answers here. How do i know that i need `samples=111` exactly? When i try 112, 200 and other numbers it does not work.

Comment: Why 111? Because it satisfies `\exists n \in\mathbb{N}: n*(50+5)+1=111`. This is the condition that a sample hits zero. The samples are take equidistantly between -5, the lower end of the domain, and 50, the upper end. So if you take 56 samples, the first one will be at -5, the next one at -4 ... and you hit 0. If you take 111, the first one will again be at -5, the next one at -4.5 ... and you hit 0. However, with samples=100 you miss 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "full rendering" of the plot can be achieved by adding an appropriate domain. The ghost ticks are minor ticks. The numbers can be made smaller by adding `ticklabel style={font=\tiny}`. The width of the plot can be controlled using the `width` key, do not use `\resizebox`. Also it is recommended to add the `compat` key.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
                axis lines=middle,
                xmin=-10, xmax=15.5,
                ymin=-200, ymax=260,
                xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={below right},
                ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={above left},
                xtick={-10,1,15},
                ytick={-200, 25, 250},
                tick style={thick},
                minor xtick={-9,-8,...,14},
                minor y tick num=10,
                ticklabel style={font=\tiny}
            ]
            \addplot[blue,thick,samples=100,domain=-10:15] {x^3-9*x^2-30*x+200};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: Plotting a stepwise defined function.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
Suppose we want to plot the function
\[ f(x)=\begin{cases}
 \frac{x^2}{2}-2x+3\;, & x\le 4\;,\\
 x-1\;, & x>4\;.
\end{cases}\]
Then one can declare a function using the `ifthenelse` function,
\begin{quote}
 \verb|declare function={f(\x)=ifthenelse(\x<=4,0.5*\x^2-2*\x+3,\x-1);}|\;.
\end{quote}
The result is shown in Figure~\ref{fig:f}.

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[declare
        function={f(\x)=ifthenelse(\x<=4,0.5*\x^2-2*\x+3,\x-1);}]
            \begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
                axis lines=middle,
                xmin=-10, xmax=15.5,
                xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={below right},
                ylabel=$f(x)$, ylabel style={above left},
                xtick={-10,1,15},
                tick style={thick},
                minor xtick={-9,-8,...,14},
                minor y tick num=1,
                ticklabel style={font=\tiny}]
            \addplot[blue,thick,samples=100,domain=-10:15] {f(x)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{$f(x)$.}      
 \label{fig:f}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It worked! :)

Comment: New problem: I want to add the declare the function ´f(x)=sqrt(x), x>=0´ How can i do this? I really dont get the adding functions system in pgfplots :b

Comment: @Nikolai Assuming you want `0` for `x<0` you need `declare function={f(\x)=ifthenelse(\x>=0,sqrt(\x),0);}`. This is equivalent to `declare function={f(\x)=sqrt(max(\x,0));}`.

Comment: I have updated the question at the top, can you take a look at it? :b It's only the part under **New Question:**.